# How to return more than 1 values at a time in php function

Tags: php, arrays, function, return, codeigniter-4

I built this php function,

```
function refs()
{
    
    $total_ref = "1111";

    $active_ref = "100";

        return ("refs") ? "$total_ref" : "";
    
}
```

Now, I want to return the **total_ref** and **active_ref** at the same time.... How do I return both as an array and call the array

if I have

```
return [
        'total_ref'  => $total_ref,
        'active_ref' => $active_ref
    ];
```

Then with $refs = refs();

how do I echo active_ref or total_ref

Comment: create an array, put the two variable into that, then return array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just return an associative array with the values.

```
function refs()
{        
    $total_ref = '1111';

    $active_ref = '100';

    return [
        'total_ref'  => $total_ref,
        'active_ref' => $active_ref
    ];
}
```

In order to echo the result of the function, you can access array elements by keys.

```
$refs = refs();
echo $refs['total_ref'];
echo $refs['active_ref'];
```

Comment: then with $refs = ref();


How do I echo each of the arrays I returned